# Is Unity going to be replaced by GNOME 3 or is it a hint of a new GNOME fork?

Tags: unity, gnome

I recently heard of the disinvestment in Unity 8 by Canonical and that they are looking at Gnome Project. Does it means that Unity will be phased out Ubuntu totally or is a indication of yet another GNOME fork??

Comment: Any answer would be conjecture.